# Proxmox. VM images

Tags: proxmox, terraform

коллеги. Тут задался вопросом, а есть ли в Proxmox возможность создания и хранения образов виртуальных машин для быстрого разворачивания, например, с помощью Terraform.

Answer (score 0):

Да, конечно. Вот описание настройки:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Telmate/proxmox/latest/docs/guides/cloud_init
Понадобится это:
https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Cloud-Init_FAQ